# Fetch data from api on stop scrolling ScrollView React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, scrollview

I'm new to react native and I want to fetch data when user stops scrolling or goes to end/bottom of the screen.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Using ScrollView you have the onScroll prop, that you can use to fire the data fetching. Personally, I recommend you use FlatList, there you have onViewableItemsChanged and onEndReached prop that you can use to do what you want. Please check the official docs for more info.

Comment: I have tried onScroll method but it calls multiple times and I wrapped my views under scrollview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056761/detect-scrollview-has-reached-the-end  this helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this  [How do I check when the user has stopped scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970315/how-do-i-check-when-the-user-has-stopped-scrolling.), but in react native best practice is to use a Flatlist (https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) when you don't know  how much data you will render